# Eclipse is saying I am missing class path entry red5.jar for Red5 plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, red5

When I went to create a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse I went to new runtime and clicked "Red5 Server Runtime". When I hit next it is saying that I am missing class path entry red5.jar. I did a search on my computer and I could not find that. What to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your [Red5 installation](http://red5world.com/index.php/red5/how-to-import-red5-into-eclipse/).

Comment: Please add a short answer here instead of just providing a link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem happen on release "red5-1.0.1". I you want avoid it, just use the release "red5-1.0.0.zip" ("http://red5.org/downloads/red5/1_0/red5-1.0.0.zip").

In alternative, you can rename the file "red5-server-1.0-bootstrap.jar" (in red5 installation folder) to "red5.jar", and it work well.